# jQuery Select Element by Data Attribute Unexpected Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

The following code should alert the HTML content of a DIV. The DIV is selected by finding its data attribute for the field panel. However the alert is undefined for reasons I cannot explain.

```
$('.access .panel').html(results).data('panel','logon');

  alert($('.access .panel[data-panel=logon]').html());
```

Comment: I've had troubles using "data" before. Try setting the "attribute" instead. $('.access .panel').html(results).attr('data-panel','logon');

Answer (score 1):

Using the `data` method to set the data for an element doesn't change the data attribute. The data attribute is the initial value, not the current value.

If you set the data attribute, you can find it using the selector:

```
$('.access .panel').html(results).attr('data-panel','logon');
```

Comment: @BhojendraSah: That returns the current value.